# If $U \subseteq F$ is open in $F$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $E$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Prove or disprove: Let $f:E \subseteq \mathbb{R^n} \to F \subseteq \mathbb{R^m}$ be a continous function. If $U \subseteq F$ is open in $F$, then $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $E$.

My attempt: My guess is that the statement is true. Since $U$ is open in $F$, then we have that $\exists A$ open in $\mathbb{R^m}$ such that $U=F\cap A$. Besides that, we have that $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $E$.  Hence $f^{-1}(U)=f^{-1}(F\cap A)$ $\subseteq f^{-1}(F)\cap f^{-1}(A)$. I'm stuck here. Would the function have to be injective?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please give your working definition of continuous. There are multiple equivalent definitions, some of which would render your question trivial.

Comment: I would observe that $f^{-1}(F) = E \supset f^{-1}(A)$, from which it follows that $f^{-1}(F) \cap f^{-1}(A) = f^{-1}(A)$

Comment: @YourongZang It needs not to be a homeomorphism.

Comment: @KeeferRowan My main definition of continuous function is: $f$ is continuous in $A$ if, for given $x \in A$ and given $\varepsilon >0$, exists some $\delta>0$ such that
$f(B_\delta(x)\cap{A})\subseteq B_\varepsilon (f(x))$

Answer (score 1):

This is true. Let V be open in $\mathbb{R}^m$. $a\in f^{-1}(V)$ $\iff$ $f(a)\in V$. Therefore, there exists a radius $r>0$ such that $B(f(a),r)\subseteq V$. As $f$ is continuous, you can find a $\delta>0$ such that $B(a,\delta)$ $\subseteq$ $f^{-1}(B(f(a),r)) \subseteq f^{-1}(V)$